# Computation of Euclidean Distance in Tensorflow isn't running on GPU

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I need to compute the euclidean distance between each image **i** in an array with **k** images **(1 <= i <= k)** with an input image ***xr<sub>j</sub>***, **(1 <= j <= m)** (the **k** images and the input image **xr<sub>j</sub>** are the column **j** of matrix **IR**). When the process finishes for all columns of **IR**, it's returned a matrix **D** with shape **k,m**, containing all the euclidean distances between each **k** image to input image **xr<sub>j</sub>**. The original code used to perform this task is shown in **Code 1**.

[image: Matrix of reduced images from MNIST]

#### Code 1

```
    D = np.zeros(shape=[ir_set[0].shape[0]-1, len(ir_set)])

    for i in range(len(ir_set)): # number of team members.
        shape = ir_set[i].shape
        qtd_images = shape[0] # number of 'k' similar images
        dim_image = shape[1:] # dimensions of the reduced image

        for j in range(qtd_images-1): 
            k = tf.placeholder(shape=dim_image, dtype=tf.float32)
            x = tf.placeholder(shape=dim_image, dtype=tf.float32)

            # L2 metric
            d = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(k, x)))) 
            distance = sess.run(d, feed_dict={k: ir_set[i][j], x: ir_set[i][qtd_images-1]})

            print('Computing distance: Model {0}/{1}, Image {2}/{3}'.format(i+1, len(ir_set), j+1, qtd_images-1), end='\r')
            D[j][i] = distance

    print('\nAll distances computed. Matrix D shape: {0}'.format(D.shape))
    return D
```

The problem with **Code 1** is that it takes too long to compute all the distances, letting my GPU idle all the time. Why this code isn't making use of my GPU, since all other Tensorflow procedures are? How can I modify **Code 1** in order to make use of the GPU and thus, run faster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the shape of ir_set? each elements of the above matrix is an image, so there should be (k+1) x m images in the IR matrix?

Comment: Yes, there are (k+1) x m elements in IR (ir_set), which are images from MNIST dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make use of `tensorflow's broadcasting` support to calculate the euclidean distance of all the image combinations at once instead of looping over each one of them.

For example:

```
k = 10
m = 5
im_size = 32*32
IR = tf.random_normal((k+1,m,im_size))
#split IR into (k,m,imsize) and (1,m,imsize)
ir, xr = tf.split(IR,[k, 1], axis=0 )

# Distance for all k*m values 
distances = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(ir, xr)), 2)
```

Your code, loops between CPU and GPU, and most of the the time is spend on CPU because of the feeding placeholders. The above one runs entirely on GPU.